# Repeated notification after downvoting an answer that gets deleted

Tags: bug, reputation, down-votes, notifications

Since the latest update when I downvote an answer that then gets deleted I get back 1 rep point but I also get notifications of the latest upvote on my account; notifications that I have already seen. In this case I get notified again of a 10+ vote from yesterday. I reproduced this issue twice. Is this a feature or a bug? I couldn't find a duplicate.

Comment: I got the same when I deleted my own answer.

Comment: To be clear: you don't see the unupvote, but you see a +10 (previously read) highlighted as a new change?  Also, what number did you see in the indicator?

Comment: Yes, I see the latest notification again, the +10.